# Passing userPrincipal to HttpServletRequest using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

I have a REST service receiving POST request. The userPrincipal is a required parameter, since it is used in other APIs. Anyway I don't seem able to pass it to the HttpServletRequest object. How can I pass him the userPrincipal value? Do I have to add it in the header, in the params, or somewhere else? Both do not seem to work.

REST service code:

```
@POST
@Path("{id}/dothings")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public Response doThings(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @PathParam("id") String id, MultipartFormDataInput payload) {
        String username = request.getUserPrincipal() != null ? request.getUserPrincipal().getName() : null;
        //username is always null
        doSomething(username, payload);
}
```

Ajax call code:

```
var param = new FormData();
param.append('param1' , value1);
param.append('param2' , value2);
$.ajax({
    url: findUrl("dothings"),
    dataType : "application/json",
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    headers: {
        "Authorization" : authAdmin, //string containing "Basic "+ base64encoding(username+":"+password), for authentication
        "Accept" : "application/json"
    },
    type:"POST",
    data: param,
    success: function(data) {
        alert("executed!");
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error while completing task: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: How is authentication configured in web.xml? For your case you will have to setup HTTP BASIC authentication.

Comment: Thanks. How can I do that? I thought I already did that on lines 9-12 of the Ajax code: it works for several other GET requests I am doing

Comment: There should be a section as: `<login-config><auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>` in your web.xml. Lines 9-12 should implement authentication from the *client's* point of view. My question is to clarify that the *server* is set up correctly too.